# Query mysql by date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query mysql by date, I have a variable of $today = date("Y-m-d");

I want to use this to get 'post_content' out of my 'posts' table for each previous year. I will then be echoing out this data using php.

How in the world would I do this? Maybe a while loop changing the date and querying that? I found "select fields from tables order by dateField" and would imagine a statement like that would exist with a parameter letting we query my posts table by year...

To clarify I am looking to query for posts annually, much like time-hop.

I have been running circles with this for about two weeks now, and help is much appreciated!

**edit current code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts
            WHERE date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
            ORDER BY date DESC";
            // SELECT * FROM conversions WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND `user_id` = '$user_id';
            $result = $dbc->query($sql);




            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $i=1;
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<li>";
                        echo "<p>".$row['post_date']."</p>";
                        // $clientid.$i =
                        echo "<h3>".$row["post_content"]."</h3>";
                        echo "</li>";
                    }//end while
                $i++;
            } else {
            echo "0 results found in user database!";
            }
```

Comment: I just found this for the first time and it may prove fruitful... SELECT * FROM conversions WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;

Comment: What have you done so far? Also, your question is not so clear. `$today` will give you today's date. So, do you want to find the posts from the previous year based on `$today`'s year?

Comment: I am currently trying to run this query: SELECT * FROM conversions WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND `user_id` = '$user_id'

Comment: $today was to reference the current date so I could, yes, find posts from the previous year based on $today's year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php code seems to be confusing the column names `date` (which appears in your `WHERE` clause) and `post_date` (which appears as a column name resulting from your `fetch_assoc()` clause. Do you actually have both `date` and `post_date` columns?

Also, it looks like the inequalities in your `WHERE` clauses might be off-by-one.

If you want to get the most recent year from today, it's

```
WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

For the year prior to that, it's

```
WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR
  AND date <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

If it's the present *calendar year* you want, use this.  It's a little complicated because it allows the use of an index on the `date` column.  The `DATE_FORMAT()` expression turns the present date, e.g. 2015-03-10, into 2015-01-01.

```
WHERE date >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01')
```

Similarly, the calendar year prior to the present one is done like this.

```
WHERE date >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
  AND date <  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01')
```

Comment: Thank you for catching my inconsistency, I did confuse date and post_date.

Answer (score 0):

From the additional information in your comments, it sounds like you want to solve it in SQL using a YEAR interval, and probably order by descending date.

```
SELECT * FROM conversions
WHERE post_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

Comment: I am sure this is going to be what I use but I am getting, Notice: Trying to get property of non-object for using $result in my while loop *code in original post above

Comment: I don't see why I couldn't work though using my while loop as I had before with this new code...

Comment: Wait a sec... I need to edit posts for 1 year ago! its empty!

Comment: I had confused date and post_date. Thanks for all of the help!